# Creating any entity record with mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

im trying to save a record on a sql server 2008 DB using entityframework and mvc3.

```
{
  using(entities store = new entities())
  {
    login log = new login() {
      Username=username,
      Thumbprint=thumbprint
    };
    store.login.AddObject(log);
    store.SaveChanges();//crashes on this line of code
  }
}
```

The code crashes and teh error is I cant save null in the Username column. My DB table does not allow null and im assigning values to the log entity object(username). If you do not understand what im trying to say, please ask.

Comment: It's my understanding that `(context).(object).add()` is antiquated, and `(context).AddTo(object)()` is the better method now... You also probably want to call `InsertOnSubmit` rather than `SaveChanges` (the latter is re-saving deltas).

Comment: Is the InsertOnSubmit a (context) method?

Comment: I may have been a little confused, heh. (coffee's still being applied). You're right about `SaveChanges`, but you should be calling `context.AddTo[model_name](<new_model>)` *then* `SaveChanges`

Comment: I tried that too.    store.AddtoLogin(log); Then I call store.SaveChanges();

Comment: And still not successful? Are you checking `if (store.SaveChanges() > 0) { /* success */ }`?

Comment: It crashed on the store.SaveChanges() method. Its brings up a SqlClient exception

Comment: What does the exception entail? That would be a good piece of information to include in your original question.

Comment: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Username', table dbo.Login'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

Comment: So there you go. Check if `String.IsNullOrEmpty(username)` before you proceed with the insert. If the test is true, you can't insert because the username's not valid for the database schema.

Comment: I checeked, its not null. just before i call the store.savechanges() i have a break point to check the values.

Comment: Fixed it. The username "StoregeneratedPattern" on the edmx was set to primary key so now i just changed it to None. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @CodeNoob: Please write this as an answer and accept your answer, so everyone can see that the problem is solved.